# Weird gap in HTML Positioning

Tags: html, css

[image: screen shot]

(In above screen shot green lines were drawn later by MS Paint and are only for describing the problem.)

Code:

```
<style>#left{float:left;width:100px;background:red;height:100%}</style>
<div id="left">SS</div>
```

So as you can see there is a weird gap in the picture and it is not fully aligned in left.

Why does this occur? How to solve it?

Comment: Add `body{margin: 0;}`

Comment: How about debugging it yourself for a second or 3? Right click -> inspect element. There ya go.

Comment: to be sure, i usually add both body and html to margin:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `body` the default margin is **8px**.

You can remove default margin:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

[image: code screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

try using a CSS reset file like [YUI Css Reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/):

> The foundational CSS Reset removes the inconsistent styling of HTML elements provided by browsers. This creates a dependably flat foundation to build upon. With CSS Reset loaded, write explicit CSS your project needs.

Answer (score 0):

set margin in your css file to 0 as body default:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

In your case, the margin is probably defined by your browsers default values.

Answer (score -1):

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Copy this code to your css. It will remove default browsers settings.